# Suspicious following activity

Tags: discussion, area-51, sock-puppets, followers

I've been following this particular proposal as I am rather intersted in it : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it

And I noticed today some fishy activity, 35 users have joined in the last 24 hours with exactly 51 rep. Only 12 of those users have set their profilenames, none of them have pictures, and the rest are user#####.

While it's very possible that someone is spreading the word-of-mouth about this proposal (great!) it also seems equally likely that someone has found a way to sock-puppet the proposal's follower count.

What's up with this?

(I'm sorry if the `discussion` tag is incorrect, I wasn't sure exactly which of the required tags was a best fit)

Comment: http://twitter.com/stevewranovsky

Comment: That was 10 days ago though, if it was yesterday it would explain. : S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry too much about sock puppets; a site consisting only of sock-puppet followers can't make it through the commitment phase.

Comment: But that sort of queers it for legitimate users of the proposal if it opens "too early" based on sock puppet votes, and is then closed before it gets a chance to take off (I'm assuming that there's a time frame where x posts, y upvotes, etc., have to occur for the site to make it).