# Is it possible for moderators to move a proposal backwards through the phases?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal, site-lifecycle

Based on the comment on [this answer from Joel S.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55113/suspicious-following-activity/55290#55290), I'm curious if a proposal can be reversed through the phases.

So for example, in the case being discussed in that question, say a bunch of sockpuppets are in on a proposal, but it's only discovered later on. Instead of closing, would the proposal be "un-committed" (that's a bad term because it means something else) from the current phase and moved to the previous phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit "un-commit" or "un-beta" function behind the scenes in Area 51.

Over time, we are going to be studying and refining what constitutes "advancing a successful site" and closing less successful ones. If we discover a flaw in the process, we'll make adjustments. If there is a *fixable* problem with the site, we'll go back and fix it (hopefully to a more successful launch later).

Our primary goal is to create successful sites. It's not like we're going to spite ourselves if something goes wrong along the way. But nobody knows what types of problems could arise, much less how we are going to handle these hypothetical glitches. But we'll handle them.

Comment: I was just curious about what functions and processes are available to moderators. Thanks for the explanation!